# NumPy vectorised method for computing covariance with population means (for survey data)

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, numpy, vectorization

I'll start with a bit of an introduction about survey data. You may skip it

## Introduction

Survey data is formed from a complex sampling pattern that survey gurus come up with. The sample can stratify a nation by state, district or county, region, locality, etc. It may even stratify people by race, income etc. Once the strata are created to address the design problem of the survey, random samples are selected from within those strata. These samples are surveyed, but since some people don't like to divulge information they consider personal, not all responses are valid. To overcome this, often strata are oversampled, so that you expect the number of correct and valid responses will at least equal your desired sample size.

When putting the responses together to perform analysis, the responses need to be weighted so that the analysis estimates what the whole population would look like based on the sample. Since sampling itself was so complex, and the sample itself is based on other surveys, and so suffers from the drawbacks in that survey, the weights are not a single number. The weights have their own distribution.

If one just want to compute a central tendency of the data, say mean, or median, the final weights should be sufficient. But results are incomplete without an idea of the spread of the central tendency. The spread is obtained from variance. For survey data, there are two variances in play, the true population variance, and the variance due to weights. This makes variance computation extremely complex and prone to errors

There are various asymptotic methods being widely used today to overcome the complexity of variance computation. One of the most popular is the Jackknife method. The Jackknife method involves deleting a part of the responses, and reweighting the remaining responses. So a 100-order Jackknife will delete 1/100th of the responses, and reweigh the remaining 99/100th responses. This will be repeated a 100 times, each time deleting a different 1/100th part of the responses. Upon completion, one will have a 100 Jackknife weights (formally called replicate weights).

Each of the 100 replicate weights will, when used like the total sample weights, give a measure of the central tendency of interest. Now, variance of the total central tendency can be computed from the central tendencies obtained from all the Jackknife weights.

## Problem Statement

I computed the true values of the population means from the total sample weights. I also computed the same measure using all the replicate weights. Now I need to estimate variance and covariance, for which, I need to subtract observations from mean of the observation.

In my case, observations are obtained from replicate weights, and mean is obtained from total weight. Prepackaged covariance functions like `numpy.cov()` compute means from the passed data array. In my case, that would give incorrect answers. Basically, I need a vectorised version of the following pseudocode:

```
def cov_var(arr, means):
    """
    arr is a matrix of experiments along rows and observations along columns
    means is a vector as long as the number of rows in arr
    """

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        s = 0
        for j in range(len(arr)):
            for k in range(len(arr[i])):
                s += (arr[i][k] - means[i]) * (arr[j][k] - means[j])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post suggests improvements over the vectorized implementation listed in [`the other solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34235453/3293881). Apart from the usual housekeeping error-checking codes, the crux of it seems to be contained in two lines -

```
arr1 = np.subtract(arr.T, means).T
cov = np.dot(arr1, arr1.T)
```

---

**Improvement #1**

The first one `np.subtract(arr.T, means).T` involves two transposes and one function call. This can be simply implemented by extending the dimensions of `means` with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and performing the subtraction. Now, both these approaches would use `broadcasting` and that is essentially the computation done here, so as such I am not expecting any significant speedup with it. The alternative code would be -

```
arr1 = arr - means[:,None]
```

Runtime test and verify -

```
In [16]: arr = np.random.rand(5000,5000)
    ...: means = np.random.rand(5000)
    ...: 

In [17]: np.allclose(arr - means[:,None],np.subtract(arr.T, means).T)
Out[17]: True

In [18]: %timeit np.subtract(arr.T, means).T
1 loops, best of 3: 346 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit arr - means[:,None]
1 loops, best of 3: 332 ms per loop
```

**Improvement #2**

Next up, `np.dot(arr1, arr1.T)` could be implemented with `np.einsum`, like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,kj',arr1,arr1)
```

Runtime test and verify -

```
In [16]: arr = np.random.rand(200,300)
    ...: means = np.random.rand(200)
    ...: 

In [17]: arr1 = np.subtract(arr.T, means).T

In [18]: np.allclose(np.dot(arr1, arr1.T),np.einsum('ij,kj',arr1,arr1))
Out[18]: True

In [19]: %timeit np.dot(arr1, arr1.T)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,kj',arr1,arr1)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.12 ms per loop
```

Comment: Awesome! When you are running over thousands of lines, I can see the milliseconds add up to make a considerable difference. My main drawback was lack of knowledge about all NumPy functions. I looked at the NumPy source code for `cov()` and they too use `dot()`, so I figured I would too. I was a bit skeptical about `dot()`, given that it has a lot of things to take care of... `einsum()` looks promising. I'll have to dig through it soon!

Answer (score 1):

After some thought and a couple of tests, I came up with the following simple code:

```
def var_covar(arr, means=None, axis=1, normalize=True, bias=None):
    """
    Computes the covariance of array arr. Optionally it takes means
    separately instead of computing it from the data.
    ----------
    PARAMETERS
    :arr: array_like; A NumPy array or other data type that can be converted
        into an NumPy array.
    :means: Optional, array_like; A vector of means for each observation in
        arr. Mostly would be population means.
    :axis: Optional, int, default 1; Operates either by row or by column.
        Default assumes experiments are along rows, and observations are
        along columns.
    :normalize: Optional, bool, default True; Normalizes the data by 1/(N-bias),
        where N is number of observations.
    :bias: Optional, float; Bias is subtracted from N, to account for sample
        mean. If means are passed, it is assumed they are population means
        and so bias is set to 0. Else to 1. Passing a value overrides the
        default value of bias.
    ----------
    RETURNS
    :cov: array_likep; A 2-D NumPy array if arr is a matrix. A float if arr
        is a vector
    ----------
    NOTES:
      Maximum number of supported dimensions is 2
      It is assumed that passed means are population means, and not sample
      means. This assumption affects bias. Pass a value for bias to override
      the default bias.
      It is recommended that length of means equals number of observations in
      arr. If that is not the case, means will be broadcast, but it may throw
      an error.
      axis must be either 0 or 1. Higher dimensions are not supported.
    """

    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    tbias = bias

    if arr.ndim > 2:
        raise RuntimeError('Cannot handle arr larger than a 2x2 matrix')

    if axis not in [0,1]:
        raise ValueError('axis must be either 0 or 1')
    elif axis == 0:
        arr = arr.T

    if means is None:
        means = np.average(arr, axis=1)
        bias = 1
    else:
        bias = 0
    means = np.asarray(means)

    arr = np.subtract(arr.T, means).T
    cov = np.dot(arr, arr.T)

    if normalize:
        if tbias is not None:
            bias = tbias
        factor = 1/(arr.shape[0] - bias)
        cov = np.multiply(cov, factor)

    return cov
```

It is relatively fast, and completely vectorised. I am sharing this for anyone else who might need it.

Please feel free to post answers if you think you have done better than me. I will gladly accept it as answer.